# Search files without specific string under current directory

Tags: linux, search, grep

I have hundreds of *.txt files in a folder, and some of them are missing '**author**' label due to incaution, now I want to find them out without manually checking one by one. 
In addition, I think it might be better to limit the search on *.txt files only (i.e. skip other types of file in the same folder).

expect output:

```
001.txt
004.txt
008.txt
009.txt
```

I know it might be related to '`grep`' or '`find`' command and I went through --help but still don't have much ideas. 
What I'm able to figure out is only to filter out all *.txt files in the folder

```
ls -ltr | grep txt
001.txt
002.txt
003.txt
004.txt
005.txt
006.txt
007.txt
008.txt
009.txt
010.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `grep -Rl 'author' --include='*.txt' .`

docs:

```
-L, --files-without-match  print only names of FILEs containing no match
-R, -r, --recursive       equivalent to --directories=recurse
    --include=FILE_PATTERN  search only files that match FILE_PATTERN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this combination of `grep` and `find`

```
find -iname "*.txt" -exec grep 'author' {} \;
```

or

```
find -iname "*.txt" -exec grep -l 'author' {} \;

 -l, --files-with-matches
              Suppress  normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning
              will stop on the first match.  (-l is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: The second command only return  filename  like matched content filename